# python decorator with javascript

Tags: javascript, decorator

What I want to do is the following :

I have a function that alert something :

```
myfunction = function(foobar) { 
                 alert(foobar); 
             };
```

Now I want to decorate it so that :

```
decorate = function(callback) { 
              return function(foobar) { 
                  callback(foobar); 
                  console.log(foobar); 
           }; 
};
```

So then I can write :

```
myfunction = decorate(myfunction);
```

And then myfunction will do the normal + log in the console.

How can I make it works with Javascript ?

Comment: Actually it does work like this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can. And in fact, you have, your implementation works perfectly: [Live example](http://jsbin.com/ojaram) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ojaram/edit)

```
var myfunction = function(foobar) { alert(foobar); };

var decorate = function(callback) { return function(foobar) { callback(foobar); console.log(foobar); }; };

var result = decorate(myfunction);

result("Hi there");
```

I would recommend using function *declarations* rather than function *expressions*, though:

```
function myfunction(foobar) {
    alert(foobar);
}

function decorate(callback) {
    return function(foobar) {
        callback(foobar);
        console.log(foobar);
    };
}

var result = decorate(myfunction);

result("Hi there");
```

And if you want to create a more generic version, look at using `apply` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) | [spec](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.3)) and the `arguments` pseudo-array ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) | [spec](http://es5.github.com/#x10.6)): [Live example](http://jsbin.com/ojaram/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ojaram/2)

```
function decorate(original, wrapper, context) {
    return function() {
        try {
            original.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        catch (e) {
        }
        try {
            wrapper.apply(context || this, arguments);
        }
        catch (e) {
        }
    };
}

function myFunction(arg1, arg2) {
    alert("arg1 = " + arg1 + ", arg2 = " + arg2);
}

var newFunction = decorate(myFunction, function(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log("arg1 = " + arg1 + ", arg2 = " + arg2);
});

newFunction(1, 2);
```

That version does a couple of things:

1. Lets you supply the callback as an argument to one central `decorate` function.
2. Lets you optionally supply a "context" (`this` value) to use when calling the callback.
3. Preserves the value of `this` when calling both the original and (if you don't supply `context`) the callback.

...which an be handy when decorating object functions (sometimes called methods).

Comment: I usually use function declaration but in that case the function are defined in a array (it is for statusCode in $.ajax()). I would be glad to see a generic version.

Comment: @Natim: Curiously enough, I just added one. :-)

Comment: The thing is sometimes the wrapper may be call before the callback and sometimes after. But your implementation is interesting.

Comment: @Natim: You could readily have the `decorate` function accept an object with keys like `before` and `after` that refer to the functions to call (with either of them being optional, of course, and presumably with `beforeContext` and `afterContext` as well).

Answer (score 3):

More generic using arguments and apply :

```
function myfunction(foobar) { 
    alert(foobar); 
}

function decorate(callback) { 
    return function() { 
        callback.apply(null, arguments); 
        console.log(arguments); 
    }; 
}

var result = decorate(myfunction);

result("Hi there");
```